# ScrollTo Anchor Element at Document Loadtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cross-browser, anchor

Someone posted this in the past so I'll re-post it considering I'd love to see if there's any custom scripts out there with this functionality. Dare I say, so I don't have to code it myself :P

Excerpt from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903574/jquery-scroll-to-anchor-when-calling-url-replace-browsers-behaviour):
"I already know the jQuery plugin ScrollTo, but I didn't find any way up to now to realize the following:

The users gets to my site (by typing, NOT by clicking a link on my page) domain.com/bla.php#foo

and the anchor "#foo" exists. Now I want that the browser of the user does NOT automatically scroll to "#foo", instead I want to smoothly scroll so that the element '#foo' is about in the middle of the view and NOT on the absolute top position of the users view.

Thanks so far!"

Comment: Guess the only true work around is to attach something to the scrolling mechanism opposed to trying to handle the anchor element on its own. For the page won't snap down to an anchor until the it's fully loaded. Time enough to bind the scrolling mechanism to a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack the solution to this. Add a script right in the  to grab the current location. Set the scrolltop to be the top of the page then add a jQuery.ready(scrollTo) block for when the page is loaded.

A pseudo-code implementation is as follows.

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js">
  <script>
    var loc = window.location;
    var anchor = getAnchor(loc);
    if (anchor !== undefined) {
      removeAnchor(loc, anchor);
      scrollTo(0);
      $.ready(function() {
        $.scollTo(anchor);
      });
    }
  </script>
  ...
```

I hope that this will trigger before the browser has a chance to snap to the anchor. It may or may not work. Feel free to flesh it out yourself.

Comment: Since you're the only one who came even close, I'll give you a thumbs up :P