# WP mobile jquery scrolltodiv from menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrollto, page-jump

I´m working on a responsive wordpress site where on small screens(mobile) I want to scroll to #content when a menu-item is clicked as the menu takes up most of the screenspace. I´ve tried these script but didn´t work.

1

```
$("#access a").click(function() {
$("#goto").animate({scrollTop: $("#goto").offset().top});
});
```

2

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#goto').offset().top }, 1000);
```

Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903574/jquery-scroll-to-anchor-when-calling-url-replace-browsers-behaviour/8733764#8733764), which worked great.

Based on that answer, try this:

```
$(function() {
var scrollElement = '#content';
var destination = $(scrollElement).offset().top;
$("#access a").click(function() {
    $(scrollElement).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
        scrollTop: destination-75 }, 800 );
    });
});​
```

Note, the number 75 can be tweaked to get the page to scroll exactly where you want it to.

Comment: Thanks! But it didn´t work. Would it be easier to force a scroll to content on page load?

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in there but I fixed it. It works now. Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/E5bLP/8/